# initializing objects in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

as you know initializing object in c# is really handy and fast

```
    StudentName student2 = new StudentName
    {
        FirstName = "Craig",
        LastName = "Playstead",
    };
```

and

```
List<MyObject>.Add(new MyObject{a=1,b=2})
```

is it possible to initializing objects in Delphi like this?

Comment: There's no answer to your question other than "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by others there is no object initializer syntax like there is in C#.

There are a few alternatives that come close.

1. [ja-mesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733070/ja-mesa) already pointed out the `with` construct, though it's best to avoid this construct. You can see my [blog](http://codeelegance.blogspot.com/2011/08/with-statement.html) for a (mostly) unbiased review of the pros and cons of using `with` as well as similar constructs in other languages and some alternatives.
2. Anonymous methods can be used for this though they're a little verbose and kind of ugly:

   ```
   TMyObject.Create(procedure(var  FirstName, LastName: string)
                    begin
                      FirstName := 'Craig';
                      LastName := 'Playstead';
                    end);
   ```
3. A fluent interface can come fairly close to approximating this:

   ```
   TMyObject.Create
            .FirstName('Craig')
            .LastName('Playstead');
   ```

   The downside being that writing a fluent interface is time consuming and only pays off if you plan on using this class a lot or are writing a public api.
4. Constant records also come very close.

   ```
   const
     MyRecord: TMyRecord =
     (
       FirstName : 'Craig';
       LastName : 'Playstead';
     );
   ```

   The obvious drawback being that it is a constant
5. Another solution would be an overloaded constructor:

   ```
   TMyObject.Create('Craig', 'Playstead');
   ```

Of course you could accomplish much the same thing by simply creating a temporary variable with a single character name.

```
var
  o: TMyObject;

begin
  o := TMyObject.Create;
  o.FirstName := 'Craig';
  o.LastName := 'Playstead';
  Result := o;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no direct equivalent in Delphi, there is something like this:

```
Student2:=StudentName.Create();
with Student2 do
begin
  FirstName:= 'Craig';
  LastName:= 'Playstead';
end;

MyObject:=TMyObject.Create();
With MyObject do
begin
    a:=1;
    b:=2;
end;
List.Add(MyObject);

// Although, there is something in Delphi that I haven't found in C++, Java or C#
With TMyObject.Create do
try
    // You can access TMyObject properties and method in here
finally
    Free;
end;

// For example:
With TMyModalForm.Create(Self) do
try
    if ShowModal() = mrOK then
    begin
        // etc
    end;
finally
    Free;
end;
```

Comment: A great example of 'with', although the keyword is [slightly dangerous.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514482/is-delphi-with-keyword-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

You can override and reintroduce `constructor Create`. I'd recommend reading [this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876040/delphi-understanding-constructors) here on StackOverflow.

Comment: That isn't what the question asks. This doesn't need any special help from the class being initialised in C#.

Comment: i know what constructor do my friend, actually my question is how to create object without declaring local variable and directly pass it to parameter argument like what i did in c#

Comment: I think what Mark means is that you can pass the parameters into the constructor, so have it all on a single line. @Mark, perhaps you could update your answer with more info?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent syntax in Delphi.  You must either `reintroduce` the constructor to add new parameters to it, or else construct the object first and then assign its members/properties as needed separately.